# Importing module from sub-package in current directory when it clashes with site-packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I have module `e` in package `a.b.c.d` in my `site-packages` directory:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/a/b/c/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/a/b/c/d/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/a/b/c/d/e.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty in both cases. I mirror this directory structure in my current directory:

```
a/b/c/__init__.py
a/b/c/d/__init__.py
a/b/c/d/e.py
```

I run python 2.7 and type:

```
from a.b.c.d.e import foo
```

The `site-packages` version is imported instead of the local version. `sys.path[0]` is the empty string. I expect and find in documentation/Google that the current directory takes precedence because of this. I've also tried adding `__init__.py` in the current directory's `a/b` and `a` directories, as well as the current directory itself.

If I rename the first directory to `z` then the local import works (with the extra `__init__.py`s in place for `z` and `b` and import statement appropriately changed).

`site-packages` contains `a.b.c-VERSION-nspkg.pth`:

`import sys,types,os; p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('a',)); ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py')); m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('a',types.ModuleType('a')); mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]); (p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
import sys,types,os; p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('a', 'b')); ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py')); m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('a.b',types.ModuleType('a.b')); mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]); (p not in mp) and mp.append(p); m and setattr(sys.modules['a'], 'b', m)`

Why can I not override the module like this? Is it perhaps because `sys.modules` already contains the module? Can I force it to be overridden somehow?

Comment: What Python version is this? In 2.x and early 3.x, `a` is not a package if it has no `__init__.py`, and neither of yours do (but the site-packages one probably explicitly adds a .pth file). In later 3.x, `a` is a namespace package and will merge the two together (but `a.b.c` is not, so one or the other has to win).

Comment: I've added further 2.7 references and details that I've tried adding more `__init__.py`s.

Comment: From the comment at the end of your question, "Is it perhaps because sys.modules already contains the module?": if you've already imported it in the current session and then try to change things (whether on the filesystem or in sys.path), then yes, that would fail. But in a new interpreter session, there's no reason these things would be in sys.modules.

Comment: When I start an interpreter `sys.modules` is not empty - I believe it contains everything from `site-packages`. The same applies on a different operating system/Python minor version.

Comment: It shouldn't be _empty_, but if it actually contains everything from `site-packages`, something is very wrong.

Comment: Ok, not all, but there are quite a few `.pth` files in there. Looks like there is one for `a.b.c`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, the problem is:

- Your `a` is not a package, because before Python 3.3, a directory without an `__init__.py` file is never a package. This means your `a.b.c` isn't a package either.
- This means the `a` in `site-packages` shouldn't a package either, but…
- There's a `.pth` file in `site` that forces the `site-packages` copy of `a.b.c` to be a package anyway.

At this point, I'm not sure what you want to do to override this. It sounds like you want to get really hacky and delete the existing package from `sys.modules` and then forcibly insert your own, or something like that. Of course you can do that, and I can show you the code if you can't guess it yourself. (Or you may want to search for `numpy_override`, which does a similar trick, for use on systems that come with an out-of-date pre-installed or system-repo-installed `numpy`.) But I think you'd be better off rethinking your problem in the first place. For example, why not just build a `virtualenv` that has your package instead of the system `site-packages` package in its `site-packages`?

Comment: I don't think this is true. As I edited into the question, the same problem occurs when `__init__.py` is added to `a` and `a/b`. I can also rename top level and import successfully, proving that it is a package.